# JSON.stringify data/child data in order to send to webapi

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Using the below code, I am able to pass this content to my webapi
which receives it like

```
public void Post(Business.Entities.api.newsalert alert)
{
    //do stuff here
}

category = $('#dt_category').val();
title = $('#inputTitle').val();
url = $('#inputURL').val();
comments = $('#inputComments').val();
subject = "News Alert / Alerte Nouvelles: " + title;

var dataJSON = {
    userid: username,
    to: "me@here.com",
    url: url,
    subject: subject,
    title: title,
    source: "My company",
    comments: comments,
    category: category
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://mywebserver/api/NewsAlerts",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        q.resolve();
    }
});
```

However, my boss has asked me to make the Categories select use multiple..

Therefore I did this

```
    category = $('#dt_category').val(); //apples, oranges, peaches
    title = $('#inputTitle').val();
    url = $('#inputURL').val();
    comments = $('#inputComments').val();
    subject = "News Alert / Alerte Nouvelles: " + title;

    var categories = [];
    $(category).each(function (index) {
        categories.push({ 'category': category[index] });
    });

    var dataJSON = {
        userid: username,
        to: "me@here.com",
        url: url,
        subject: subject,
        title: title,
        source: "My company",
        comments: comments,
        category: categories 
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://mywebserver/api/NewsAlerts",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            q.resolve();
        }
    });
```

But when my webapi receives the ajax Put, it is always null.  I'm assuming I need to somehow make the Categories into some kind of a child node but i'm not sure.

Comment: is your model `Business.Entities.api.newsalert` expecting a list ? 
meaning `Business.Entities.api.newsalert.Category` is `typeof List<int>`

Comment: you can try by changing `category` datatype as `List<string>`

Comment: Duh, hadn't considered my business object might be the problem, just assumed it would be the json serialistion. Will give it a look, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api request object should contain a property that is some collection type of a class with the property "category".

```
public class newsalert
{
     //Other Properties         

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
     IList<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}

public class Category
{
     public string category {get;set;}
}
```